# How to check if property of an objects of array matches with one of the values in another array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I know the header is way too complicated but that's how it is right now. Let me make it more clear for you.

There is an object like

```
const users= [
{
id:"1",
name:"John",
mail:"aaa@gmail.com",
},
{
id:"2",
name:"Joe",
mail:"bbb@gmail.com",
},
]
```

Then there is

```
const attendingUsers = [
{
id:"1",
name:"John",
mail:"aaa@gmail.com",
.....
},
{
id:"2",
name:"Joe",
mail:"bbb@gmail.com",
.....
},}
]
```

Both of the arrays has different properties and I just want to get the ones that are important to me. What I need is to look through `users` array and find the ones that has the same ids as the ones from `attendingUsers`.

I have came up with `users.filter(user => user.id == attendingUsers.map(attendingUser => attendingUser.id));` but that is simply returning empty array. Any idea what would be the best way to tackle this sort of a problem?

Comment: `user.id` is a number and `attendingUsers.map(attendingUser => attendingUser.id)` is an *array of strings*, they're not going to be equal (unless the array has only one value and that is equal to the string of the ID, because of the way JS stringifies arrays and the non-strict comparison `==`). You presumably want to know if `user.id` is **in** that array, not equal to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you'll have to make sure if the ID types are correct. Users has Number type for IDs but attendingUsers has String type.

Let's say they're both the same type for the code below (I'm going with string).

You can turn the attendingUsers array into an array of strings with:

```
const attendingUsersIds = attendingUsers.map(attendingUser => attendingUser.id)
```

Then match the ids with:

```
const matchedUsers = users.filter(user => attendingUsersIds.includes(user.id))
```

If they're intended to not be the same type, you can use `user.id.toString()` to turn the Number into a String or `parseInt(attendingUser.id)` to turn the String into a Number.

Comment: I guess the problem is not about ids since I compare it with ``==`` but more about the logic. Your solution solves my problem already. Thanks a lot for the effort to explain it!

Comment: `==` is fine if you're not sure about the type and just want to compare by value, but this wasn't the situation to use it. The issue with your solution was explained by [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe). I'm happy to have helped you, bro. Have a good one!

Answer (score 2):

We can use Array.map to create a new array of users, with a property *isAttending* added to each user.

We determine if they are attending by using [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to search for any matching attendee with the same id.

```js
const users = [
    {
        id:1,
        name:"John",
        mail:"aaa@gmail.com",
    },
    {
        id:2,
        name:"Joe",
        mail:"bbb@gmail.com",
    },
    {       
        id:3,
        name:"Alice",
        mail:"ccc@gmail.com",
    }
]

const attendingUsers = [
    {
        id:"1",
        name:"John",
        mail:"aaa@gmail.com",

    },
    {
        id:"2",
        name:"Joe",
        mail:"bbb@gmail.com",
    }
] 

const result = users.map(user => { 
    return { ...user, isAttending: attendingUsers.some(({id}) => id == user.id) };
});
console.log("Users (with attending property):", result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort Terry! It gives me another perspective to look in to the problem.

Comment: Great, glad to be of assistance!